# Source build of Rquantlib fails

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm building Rquantlib from source and I recently have been encountering this issue:

> Error in .Call("RQuantLib_setEvaluationDate", PACKAGE = "RQuantLib", evalDate) : 
>     "RQuantLib_setEvaluationDate" not available for .Call() for package "RQuantLib"
>   Error : unable to load R code in package ‘RQuantLib’

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Rcpp version 0.12.4

I have checked and `setEvaluationDate()` is there with appropriate rcpp tags, so not sure what's changed. I have not edited the file. It seems to be an inline version, wheras the github version is an actual call:

My rcpp generated inlcude verion for the function:

```
inline bool setEvaluationDate(QuantLib::Date evalDate) {
     typedef SEXP(*Ptr_setEvaluationDate)(SEXP);
     static Ptr_setEvaluationDate p_setEvaluationDate = NULL;

 }
```

From github:

```
bool setEvaluationDate(QuantLib::Date evalDate);
static SEXP RQuantLib_setEvaluationDate_try(SEXP evalDateSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< QuantLib::Date >::type     evalDate(evalDateSEXP);
    __result = Rcpp::wrap(setEvaluationDate(evalDate));
    return __result;
END_RCPP_RETURN_ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *recompile* all dependents of Rcpp after major upgrades.

Eg when we went from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 which changed the compiler to g++-5 with its new ABI, ran this this script to rebuild everything from the local repo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env r

## installed packages
IP <- installed.packages()

## all local packages
AP <- available.packages(contrib.url(getOption("repos")[["local"]]))

## all packages known to us
allAP <- available.packages()

pkgs <- "Rcpp"
deps <- tools::package_dependencies(packages=pkgs, db=IP, reverse=TRUE)

## set of dependencies
alldeps <- unique(sort(do.call(c, deps)))
cat("Installing these:\n")
print(alldeps)

## this makes sense on Debian where no packages touch /usr/local
libloc <- Sys.getenv("LIBLOC", unset="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")

install.packages(alldeps, lib=libloc)
```

It is similar when something in Rcpp changes, though we've been pretty good about not changing interfaces.  But when in doubt, rebuild.  Also re-run `compileAttributes()` if in doubt but little changed there.

*Edit:* I just (re-)installed without a glitch on two systems too.

*Edit 2:* It also works directly at the R prompt:

```
## what follows was one line in R and just broken up for display 
R> cppFunction("bool mySetEvalDate(QuantLib::Date d) "
              "{ QuantLib::Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = d;"
              " return true; }", depends="RQuantLib")
R> mySetEvalDate( Sys.Date() )
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Now, if your intent was to call `setEvaluationDate()` from C++ then you need to look at the discussion about exporting to R *and C++* in the Rcpp Attributes vignettes.  The code in `src/daycounter.cpp` is meant for R.

Comment: I suspect it's the environment. This all started after installing Rcpp Examples. I rebuilt per above recommendation and still no joy. I rolled back Rcpp all the way back to last summer, no joy. The key seems to be "inline" versus actual function with interface.

Comment: The argument against this line of reasoning is many of the test machine have multiple (or in the case of my box *all*) Rcpp reverse dependencies installed.  Those would *almost surely* show interactions, but they don't.

Comment: I gave up and moved my development to my Mac work station where all is well. I will come back to this and probably rebuild my centos environment when I have more time.

Comment: Hm. CentOS should not matter even though it tends to have jurassic compilers.  What g++ version was that?    On Linux, both Debian and Ubuntu tend to _just work_.